# The difference between getString() and optString() in Json

Tags: java, json, org.json

What is the difference between `getString()` and `optString()` in JSON?

Comment: `optString` can be useful in situations where you aren't confident that the JSON request format will remain the same... i.e., calling `getString` on a JSON request might work at first, but if it changes in the future such that the key no longer exists, an exception will be thrown and your app may crash.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

As Diego mentions, it's a good idea to check the [documentation](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString%28java.lang.String%29) (this link is now out of date - good thing we have the [Wayback Machine!](https://web.archive.org/web/20150101212410/http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString(java.lang.String))) before posting a question here, but now that you have:

The difference is that `optString` returns the empty string (`""`) if the key you specify doesn't exist. `getString` on the other hand throws a `JSONException`. Use `getString` if it's an error for the data to be missing, or `optString` if you're not sure if it will be there.

Edit: Full description from the documentation:

> Get an optional string associated with a key. It returns an empty string if there is no such key. If the value is not a string and is not null, then it is converted to a string.

Comment: FYI: providing a second string as a parameter will be used as a default value if the key specified doesn't exist.

Comment: Upvoting cuz I got to know about the Wayback Machine. It's super amazing.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to avoid `NullPointerException` you better make use of `optString()`

If you  are fetching the data from `JSON` at any time, you might have `null` data for a particular Key value, at that time instead of implementing Null conditions, better make use of this optimized method `optString("<keyname>")`

Answer (score 1):

public java.lang.String optString(int index)
Get the optional string value associated with an index. It returns an empty string if there is no value at that index. If the value is not a string and is not null, then it is coverted to a string.
Parameters:
index - The index must be between 0 and length() - 1.
Returns:
A String value.

Answer (score 1):

1) **getString (String name):-** This method Returns the String value mapped by name if it exists, coercing it if necessary, or **throws JSONException** if no such mapping exists.

2)**optString (String name):-** This method Returns the String value mapped by name if it exists, coercing it if necessary, or the **empty string ("")** if no such mapping exists.

Answer (score 1):

> optString() is used to overcome NullPointerException, which we get while using getString() when the required key doesn't exists in json it basically replaces with the default value.

example let the input Json be

```
{
"name":"abhi",
"country":"india"
}
```

now in java when you execute

```
String city = json.getString("city");
```

it will throw a `NullPointerException`.

by using `optString(String key, String default)` we can overcome the above problem.

```
String city= json.optString("city","default");

System.out.println(city);
```

**Output: default**