# How Do I create a Json Array in a Json Array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

Here is my server that I am trying to parse

```
    [
  {
   "Hello": "How are You?",
"GoodBye": "I will see you later",
"Today": "How is it outside today",
"Date": "what is the date today",
"Weather": "10 degrees",
"Subcategory": [
  {
    "text": "Text goes here",
          }
{
    "text": "Text goes here",
          }
{
    "text": "Text goes here",
          }]
  [
  {
   "Hello": "How are You?",
"GoodBye": "I will see you later",
"Today": "How is it outside today",
"Date": "what is the date today",
"Weather": "10 degrees",
"Subcategory2": [
{
    "text": "Text goes here",
          }
{
    "text": "Text goes here",
          }
{
    "text": "Text goes here",
          }]
  [
```

Additionally, below I have my JSON parse for the text alone, however, I would like to get the text of the weather.

Comment: Please post valid JSON.

Comment: your parsing is completely wrong

Comment: Vivek, its not....it works, for a single arrays

Comment: Please post Full and Valid JSON, that's what i mean :)

Comment: Shoeb, I edited it and did that

Comment: Also I hope the question is clear in intent

Comment: no effort to even post a valid json, Please validate your json using any of the online validator, http://jsonlint.com/ is one of them .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text` key is inside `Subcategory` `JSONArray`, so need to get JSONArray first then get `text` String from it:

```
JSONObject currentQuestions = response.getJSONObject(x);
JSONArray arrSubcategory=currentQuestions.optJSONArray("Subcategory");
for (int y = 0; y < arrSubcategory.length(); y++) {
   JSONObject objectSubcategory = arrSubcategory.getJSONObject(y);
   String text = objectSubcategory.optString("text");
}
```

**NOTE:**

if `Subcategory` JSONArray key name is dynamic like `Subcategory,Subcategory1,...` then do it as:

```
JSONObject currentQuestions = response.getJSONObject(x);
Iterator<String> iter = currentQuestions.keys();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String key = iter.next();
    JSONArray arrSubcategory=currentQuestions.optJSONArray(key);
    for (int y = 0; y < arrSubcategory.length(); y++) {
       JSONObject objectSubcategory = arrSubcategory.getJSONObject(y);
       String text = objectSubcategory.optString("text");
    }
}
```

Comment: so I see you put JSONObject currentQuestions = response.getJSONObject(x);

Comment: are u creating another for loop? if so can you include that?

Comment: @eli: Yes eli because `Subcategory ` is JSONArray of JSONObject so need to use another loop. do it let me know if getting any issue

Comment: @eli: also see my edit answer which may be more useful

Comment: I only got the first  "text": "Text goes here",

Comment: @eli: then what you want?

Comment: Awesome job!, but can you please explain what optString is I use toString and I have never seen that what is it?

Comment: @eli: see [JSON: the difference between getString() and optString()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790726/json-the-difference-between-getstring-and-optstring) very useful

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this.

```
JSONArray array=new JSONArray(Your JSONObject);
```

Now the above is the Main JSONArray.

```
JSONArray newArray=new JSONArray();
for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
 JSONObject objmain=array.getJSONObject(i);
 JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
 obj.put("your key","your value");
 newArray.put(obj);
 objmain.put("New array key",newArray);
}
```

Comment: Bro, its already been answered but I appreciate the alternative way