# How change Textcolor for only one String in for loop?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

A basically question-> because i cant find a answer since a lot of days...
if i have a `for loop` (10 times) and each output is a different `string`. How can i make a specific `String-output` colored?

```
for(int i=0; i< posts.length();i++ ) {
        JSONObject post = posts.optJSONObject(i);
        this.title = post.optString("title");

        blogTitles[i] = title;
        }
```

Sure i can sort the specific `blogtitles[i]` by code

```
title.toLowerCase().contains("neune")
```

but if i try to give it the new `layout`, he `layout` is used for all (10x) outputs
any can help?

Thx for answer now i changed to

```
JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);
            this.title = post.getString("title");
```

but still all outputs are black and in layout "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1"

complete code

```
for(int i=0; i< posts.length();i++ ) {
            JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);
            this.title = post.getString("title");


            arrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.mytextview, blogTitles1);
            arrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, blogTitles2);



            if (title.toLowerCase().contains("neune") && title.contains(this.id.toLowerCase())) {         //ean nicht neu (!kontrolliert!)



               //     listView.setTheme(R.layout.mytextview);
                    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);
                    String title2= title.replace("neune*", "");
                    String title3 = title2.replace(this.id + ",", "-eigene Bewertung");
                    blogTitles1[i] = title3;
                    bewertungseingabe.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bewertungsueberschrift.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bewertbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    editBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

            if (title.toLowerCase().contains("neune") ) {
                listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2);
                    String title2= title.replace("neune*", "error!!!!");
                    String title3 = title2.replace(this.id + ",", "*");
                    blogTitles2[i] = title3;

            }

            if (title.toLowerCase().contains("neuja")&& title.contains(this.id.toLowerCase())) {            //ean neu (!noch nicht kontrolliert!)

                    String title2= title.replace("neuja*", "");
                    String title3 = title2.replace(this.id + ",", "-eigene Bewertung");
                    blogTitles1[i] = title3;

            }
            if (title.toLowerCase().contains("neuja") ) {
                    blogTitles2[i] = "Dieser Artikel ist in Ordnung!";

            }

            if (title.toLowerCase().contains("ganz")) {          //ean neu (!noch nicht kontrolliert!)
                blogTitles2[i] = "Du hast uns so eben eine neue EAN mitgeteilt" +
                        "füge eine Bezeichnung und Bewertung hinzu, wenn du magst...";
              //  zaehler[i]=blogTitles[i];

            }


        }
```

only the second layout is used.... i guess it is because "title.toLowerCase().contains("neune") && title.contains(this.id.toLowerCase())" is true and "title.toLowerCase().contains("neune")" is true.... it "must" be this way, because each (i)output should be evaluated

Comment: use `post.getJsonObject(i)`

Comment: you mean post.getJsonObject(i).contains("neune")? (sry i am very newbie at android)

Comment: @Newbster optstring is a good way compared to getString().http://stackoverflow.com/a/13790789/3960700

Answer (score 0):

Parse `Json` as follows.

```
JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);
this.title = post.getString("title");
```

Comment: thanks but it still nord work... all looking in  layout "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1" (watch main asking for the update of code)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
        String getStr;

```
    for(int i=0; i< posts.length();i++ ) {
    JSONObject post = posts.optJSONObject(i);
    this.title = post.optString("title");

     blogTitles[i] = title;

       getStr = blogTitles[i];

     if("neune".equals(getStr)){

    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

    SpannableString redSpannable= new SpannableString(getStr);
     redSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, getStr, 0);
     builder.append(redSpannable);


    }
```

Comment: i cant use equals because title is a packet of informations like "neune, blabla, more of bla bla, android id, bla" 

at this packet it should find "neune"  sort it specify with the help of this word and use the other subsets later....

but i will try the spannableStringbulder... Need some time to think about this part

Comment: i can not use red.length() "cannot resolve symbole 'red' "

Comment: its not working failures.... "getstring" is a String right? than i cannott use it at "redSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, getStr, 0);" a int is required and otherwise i cannot use equals see further post ->the input string is a packet...