# JSON parsing exception org.json.JSONException: No value

Tags: android, json

I am getting following JSON string that I need to parse:

```
response => {
    "error":false,
    "uid":39,
    "user":{
        "name":"my username",
        "email":"solinpromey@gmail.com",
        "created_at":"2019-05-15 13:22:19",
        "updated_at":null,
        "imagen":null,
        "nombre":null,
        "apellidos":null,
        "nivel_usuario":null,
        "id_usuario":39,
        "unique_id":null,
        "verified":null,
        "cel_verificado":null,
        "tel":"123456789",
        "code_cel":null
    }
}
```

I need to get the values for the fields inside key user.

I am trying as follows, but not working:

```
String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
```

Here I am getting an exception:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for error_msg
```

and consequently, the following lines are not executed:

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
String email = user.getString("email");

Log.d("RESPUESTA", "RESPUESTA email" + email);
```

Comment: There is no field named `"error_msg"` in your response.
Maybe "error"?
And the type of this field is **boolean**, not **string**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because your JSON does not have a property named `error_msg`. It *does* have one named `error`, so perhaps that is what you are looking for (though it is a `boolean`, not a `String`, and it is at the top level, not inside the `user` object).

Answer (score 0):

Use `optString()` it will not give you exception

Also make sure what type of field is `error_msg`

Like if its a `String` use this

```
String error_msg= address.optString("error_msg")
```

for `boolean` use this

```
 boolean error_msg= address.optBoolean("error_msg")
```

**Code snippet**

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
String email = user.getString("email");
String error_msg= address.optString("error_msg") //string type field use optBoolean for boolean
Log.d("RESPUESTA", "RESPUESTA email" + email);
```

More explanation here
[The difference between getString() and optString() in Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790726/the-difference-between-getstring-and-optstring-in-json/13790789)