# Issue with converting string to json in Java

Tags: java, json, string, api, response

I'm new in Java and I'm creating a web app using Servlet in Eclipse. 
I want to convert string to JSON using this code :

```
import org.json.JSONException; 
import org.json.JSONObject;

JSONObject jsonObject = null;
jsonObject = new JSONObject(STRING);

System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("PROPERTY_NAME"));
```

It works fine if `STRING` be equal to `"{'status':0}"` and `jsonObject.getString("status")` gives me `0`.

But I get a response from API like `"{"status":0}"` and `jsonObject.getString("status")` gives me error because `jsonObject` is :

> {}

And the error is :

> org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["status"] not found.

Do you have any solution about this?

Comment: which lib are you using? That example you have given - that _{"status":0}_ - is a valid JSON string.

Comment: I'm using `org.json.JSONException` and `org.json.JSONObject`

Comment: That library is used by a lot and does the job. (there is a `jsonObject.has(<keyname>)`) check if you want to check its keys safely. See if the "STRING" is actually that string you have passed on.

Comment: actually my response is too long and status is just one part of it. i don't know but maybe there is an issue in response structure.

Comment: well, there are online JSON string validators. Maybe you can use one of these to see if it is valid. But that library throws a JSONException if the string is not a valid JSON String. It is best to debug it. You said that using `jsonObject.getString("status")` gives an error. Can you post it? It might be that yours `status` is just on another place in the structure.

Comment: error added to question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The difference between getString() and optString() in Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790726/the-difference-between-getstring-and-optstring-in-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your double quotes in your `STRING` variable:

```
"{\"status\":0}"
```

You can do that programmatically like that (we need to call `toString()` because `STRING` is an instance of StringBuilder):

```
String escapedJsonStr = STRING.toString().replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. `STRING` is `StrngBuilder` and I give this error on replaceAll : `The method replaceAll(String, String) is undefined for the type StringBuilder`

Answer (score 2):

Problem is with the value not key. i've tested this, it works

```
JSONObject jsonObject = null;
jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\"status\":0}");
System.out.println(jsonObject.getInt("status"));
```

or this

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = null;
 jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\"status\":'0'}");
 System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("status"));
```

Comment: fyi, it does not matter. If the value is an number, `getString` will give a String representation of it. If you don't believe me, check its source code: [JSONObject.getString](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/f2f7880a40aed1c8d9c27db49226e47396556aac/libcore/json/src/main/java/org/json/JSONObject.java#511) then [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/f2f7880a40aed1c8d9c27db49226e47396556aac/libcore/json/src/main/java/org/json/JSON.java#82) which does a `String.valueOf(<your number>)`

Comment: @KarelG You're assuming that OP uses Android and not for example this here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json. That lib does fail on `0`, not on `'0'`. I currently see no hint what OP really uses, but since there is TomCat in the Stacktrace, I doubt it is Android.

Comment: I'm creating a web application (servlet) in eclipse.

Comment: you can use the approach I mentioned in my answer it will work. I used this mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json as my lib.

Comment: Actually problem was not because of value. both of `getInt` and `getString` works fine for `"{\"status\":0}"`. My problem was changing `"{"status":0}"` to `"{\"status\":0}")` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**I can help you with below example...**

> for (String key: jsonObject.keySet()){
>       System.out.println(key); }

**This will fetch you the set of Keys in the JSON.**

> JSONObject json_array = args.optJSONObject(0);
>
> Iterator keys = json_array.keys();
>
> while( keys.hasNext() ) {
>       String key = (String) keys.next();
>       System.out.println("Key: " + key);
>       System.out.println("Value: " + json_array.get(key)); }

[I recommend following the link for a thorough understanding of Java and JSON -- Example](http://deepakbaliga.com/index.php/2015/09/19/json-is-easy/)